# "Array index is less than one" WINBUGS Error

Tags: bayesian, bugs, error-message

```
for (i in 1:160) {
    situps[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],prec[gender[i]+1]);
    mu[i] <- b0+b1[gender[i]]+b2[health[i]]+b1b2[health[i],gender[i]];
}
b0 ~ dnorm(0,.001);
for (i in 1:4) {
    b2[i] ~ dnorm(0,.001);
}
for (j in 1:2) {
    b1[j] ~ dnorm(0,.001);
    prec[j] <- pow(sigma[j],-2);
    sigma[j] ~ dunif(0,10);
}
for (i in 1:4) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
        b1b2[i,j] ~ dnorm(0,.001);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this gives me the error "array index is less than one" because I clearly have all of my arrays starting at 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How is gender coded? Your use of `prec[gender[i]+1]` looks problematic. Try something like

```
situps[i]~dnorm(mu[i],tau[i])
tau[i] <- prec[gender[i]] # or some similar function
mu[i]<-b0+b1[gender[i]]+b2[health[i]]+b1b2[health[i],gender[i]]
```

NB you don't need the semi-colons at the end of each line

Comment: Indexing with `gender[i] + 1` doesn't seem as problematic as indexing with `gender[i]` and `health[i]` in this case.